# Any online access to Suchostaw, Galicia or Sukhostav, Ukraine church records from 1880s?

Tags: birth-records, church-records, 1880s, ukraine

I'm looking for family information on Tymko or Tomko Napadij.  He is my great grandfather and was born October 25, 1886.  He emigrated to Winnipeg, Canada via Halifax.  Are there any Austrian/Galician online church records for 1880s?  I found a work record from 1913 of a Witka Napadij and don't know how she may be related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer covers the access to Ukrainian archives only.
Two caveats:

- **No online access**. Unfortunately, most of documents (especially before 1919) are in paper form. Get ready to work with officials and archives.
- **People don't speak English**. Quite often, officials communicate in Ukrainian only. So you may need someone who speaks Ukrainian to proceed.

---

1. Suchostaw is now part of Ternopil region, so the first contact should be [**The State Archive of Ternopil region**](http://www.dato.te.gov.ua/).
2. The site has English interface (auto-translated using Google service), and most of hosted PDF/DOC documents are in Ukrainian.
3. Then you follow the [**Requests**](http://www.dato.te.gov.ua/index.php/zvernennia-hromadian/formy-zapytiv) page, and the second link is "Sample requests" that directs you to a long DOC file.
4. Within the document, one request that looks like what you need is on Page 12:

   > Please provide a birth certificate and photocopy of the metric record (or only a photocopy of the metric record) of *surname, first name, patronymic* who was born in ______________ district _________________ in _______ year.
   >   Father: __________________
   >   Mother: __________________
5. You may also want to check for [Paid Services](http://www.dato.te.gov.ua/index.php/zvernennia-hromadian/platni-posluhy) they provide.

---

I have checked briefly, and **Tymko Napadij** in Cyrillic, it would be **Тимко Нападій** seems to be a legit Ukrainian name:

**Tymko** (Тимко) is a short name for Тимофей (Tymothy),
and **Napadiy** (Нападій) looks like a popular family name specifically in Suchostaw.

Wikipedia [suggests](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2) that some of prominent citizens of Suchostaw were:

- Ye. Napadiy (Є. Нападій), a linguist;
- S. Napadiy (С. Нападій), an OUN/UPA leader.

Also, [searching](https://www.google.com/search?q="%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B9"+%D1%81%D1%83%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2) for 'Napadiy Suchostaw' (in Ukrainian) shows some people who live there.

Best luck in your research.

P.S. The full name of **Witka** Napadij is Viktoria/**Victoria**, and another contraction for it is **Vita/Wita**.

Comment: Thank you so very much!  This is super helpful.  I truly appreciate you looking into my family name.  It looks like I will need to ask for help to go further.  I am in Poland now and would like to go to Ukraine soon.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a bit of luck looking at [geneteka.genealodzy.pl](https://geneteka.genealodzy.pl). It is a Polish site, but it includes records from when Poland was larger - and does have some Ukrainian & Lithuanian records.

However, searching for 'Napadij' doesn't turn up any hits.

Comment: Thank you so very much Marshall.  I will check it out and also try the spelling provided by bytebuster of Napadiy.